# How to properly use __repr__ when two classes are involved

Tags: python, repr

I am working on some Python code where I create a basic ATM. The issue I am having is I am not able to get the result that I want its printing "<'function Account.balance at 0x012CBC90>" Instead of the actual balance number. So far I have only tested using jsmith. Feel free to call out any other issues that may cause a problem later.

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self,user,pin,balance):
        self.user = user
        self.pin = pin
        self.balance = int(balance)

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user

    def get_pin(self):
        return self.pin

    def balance(self):
        return int(self.balance)

    def setBalance(self,newBalance):
        self.balance = newBalance

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.user) + " " + str(self.pin) + " " + str(self.balance)


class ATM:

    def withdraw(self,Person,amount):
        result = Person - amount
        return result


    def check(self,Person):
        Person = Account.balance
        return str(Person)

    def transfer(self,id1,id2):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self



    def main():

    Chase = ATM()

    Database = []

    Teron_Russell = Account("trussell",1738,0)
    Joe_Smith = Account("jsmith",1010,1350)

    print(Teron_Russell)

    Database.append(Teron_Russell)
    Database.append(Joe_Smith)

    print("Welcome to the ATM")
    id  = input("Please enter your user ID: ")
    pin = input("Enter your pin: ")
    chosen = ""

    for i in Database:
        print("Test1")
        name = Account.get_user(i)
        print(name)
        checkPin = Account.get_pin(i)
        print(checkPin)
        if id == name and pin == checkPin:
            chosen = i

    choice = input("What would you like to do. (Type 'Check','Withdraw','Transfer': ")

    if(choice == "Check" or "check"):
        print(Chase.check(chosen))



    # if(choice == "Withdraw" or "withdraw"):
    #     wAmount = eval(input("How much would you like to Withdraw: "))
    #  #   Chase.withdraw(Account.balance,)
    # elif(choice == "Check" or "check"):
    #             Chase.check()
    # else:
    #     print("Invalid Choice!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named a variable and a method the same name, so the interpreter is confused on which one to use. Change the name of either the method or variable `balance` and you won't have this problem. Additionally, this isn't java, and you shouldn't use classes for no reason. Since you aren't using any instance variables, it is pointless to have all of those methods inside that class.

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that I named them the same.